# Subtração de datas e retornar a quantidade de anos, meses e dias

Tags: javascript, html

Através de dois `input='text'` lanço a data inicial e a data final. Por JavaScript quero subtrair a data final pela inicial e retornar a quantidade de anos, meses e dias. Estou utilizando a função `Date()`, mas consigo retornar apenas a quantidade de dias. Pela função `Date()` consigo retornar este valor?

**JavaScript**

```
var data_inicial = document.getElementById('data_inicial').value;
var data_final = document.getElementById('data_final').value;

if(data_inicial != '' && data_final != ''){
    var date_admissao = new Date(data_inicial.substr(6,4), data_inicial.substr(3,2)-1, data_inicial.substr(0,2));
    var date_demissao = new Date(data_final.substr(6,4), data_final.substr(3,2)-1, data_final.substr(0,2));
    var dias_total = Math.ceil((date_demissao.getTime()-date_admissao.getTime())/1000/60/60/24);

    alert(dias_total);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="data_inicial" id="data_inicial">
<input type="text" name="data_final" id="data_final">
```

Comment: Por que você não usa os dias totais para ter anos, meses e dias?

Comment: @ErlonCharles Não é duplicata. Veja que eu digo que a subtração funciona. O questionamento é o retorno desta subtração.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar o `Date()` não possui esta funcionalidade?

Comment: Não, isso deve ser feito na mão, mas são cálculos relativamente simples.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar são simples se se ignorar anos bisextos/comuns e se se ignorar meses com 28/30 ou 31 dias... caso contrário não são tão simples...

Comment: Já tentou fazer a subtração atômica? Pegando ano, meses e dias. Ainda que seja um pouco complicado o tratamento, deverá ser mais fácil de fazer do que pegando o total de dias.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Tentei, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo os métodos para vc recuperar a diferença de anos, meses e dias.

```
//Diferença de anos
function diferencaAnos(date1, date2) {
  var dateParts1 = date1.split('-')
    , dateParts2 = date2.split('-')
    , d1 = new Date(dateParts1[0], dateParts1[1]-1, dateParts1[2])
    , d2 = new Date(dateParts2[0], dateParts2[1]-1, dateParts2[2])

  return new Date(d2 - d1).getYear() - new Date(0).getYear() + 1;
}

//Diferença de meses
function diferencaMeses(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}

//Diferença dias
function diferencaDias(date1, date2) {

    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

    var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

    return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)

}

//Diferença anos, meses e dias
function diferencaAnoMesDia(date1, date2) {
    return "Anos: " + diferencaAnos(date1,date2)+" Meses: " + diferencaMeses(date1,date2)" + Dias: " + diferencaDias(date1,date2);
}
```

Comment: Não Leandro, estas funções são para cálculos separadamente. Na realidade, o que preciso é subtrair duas datas e informar desta subtração a quantidade de anos, meses e dias.

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta adicionando outro método para fazer isso

Answer (score 1):

Nesta função você pode passar por parâmetro qual retorno você deseja, você pode também personalizar para deixar mais genérica para o seu caso:

```
function getDateDiff(date1, date2, interval) {
    var second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24,
    week = day * 7;
    dateone = new Date(date1).getTime();
    datetwo = (date2) ? new Date().getTime() : new Date(date2).getTime();
    var timediff = datetwo - dateone;
 secdate = new Date(date2);
 firdate = new Date(date1);
    if (isNaN(timediff)) return NaN;
    switch (interval) {
    case "anos":
        return secdate.getFullYear() - firdate.getFullYear();
    case "meses":
        return ((secdate.getFullYear() * 12 + secdate.getMonth()) - (firdate.getFullYear() * 12 + firdate.getMonth()));
    case "semanas":
        return Math.floor(timediff / week);
    case "dias":
        return Math.floor(timediff / day);
    case "horas":
        return Math.floor(timediff / hour);
    case "minutos":
        return Math.floor(timediff / minute);
    case "segundos":
        return Math.floor(timediff / second);
    default:
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Utilização:

```
 dias = getDateDiff('2012-12-25', new Date(), 'dias');
 meses = getDateDiff('2012-12-25', new Date(), 'meses');
 anos = getDateDiff('2012-12-25', new Date(), 'anos');
```

Segue também o **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGKEH/)**